# Hide Values to To allow Filter Passing in Tableau?

Tags: tableau-desktop

I suspect this is not possible, but it just blows my mind that Tableau is limited in such a way. I am using a single data set with 10 filters. On my main dashboard I have 3 charts all cutting the data up in different way on by Product Sold over time, one by Products inventoried over time and another showing product prices averaged over time. (to keep it simple.) All 10 filter work on all 3 chart and all 3 chart can filter all 3 charts. Now my boss doesn't like having to click the drill down button and wants to click the Graph and have it go to another Tab and have it be the drill down.

Step 1 was easy enough create a massive tabular sheet with all the 14 column and included the same 10 filters from the original dashboard landing.

Step 2 was also easy create an action so when you click one of the 3 chart it goes to the drill down.

Step 3 now is where I hit the issue. Since none of my 3 charts use all of the fields in the 10 filters it is impossible to pass them. For example none actually have Product on the chart. We have WAY to many products so that is a Single Drop down filter. Similar Cost center is not on any because there are way to many so it's a dynamic multi drop down that adjust based on the other parameters. Some of the charts only actually have 3-4 fields of the 10.
I Have tried to put them on as Tool Tips, but delete them out so they do not show. No dice. Tried Labels or Detail then delete them out of them message to hide them, but even then I get divisions in my bar charts so rather then 39 SOLD 153 Inventory now I have it partitioned in ever possible way the 10 filters can go. Is there simply no way to build a drill down?

Comment: This doesn't seem to be a Snowflake question.  Wouldn't Tableau tags be more appropriate?

Comment: Sorry brain sludge. I was connecting to Snowflake and my brain stalled.

Answer (score 1):

Add the fields that you need interaction for to the filter section of your worksheets and when prompted for what you want to filter on, select *use all*.

Additionally right click the existing fields in that filter pane on any given worksheet and choose *apply to worksheets* -> *all using this data source* and it will add the filter to the other worksheets using the same datasource.

[image: See an example of the filter pane here.]
As you can see above, I have the ability to filter my data on city but my visualization is only displaying state. From here I would bring this viz to my dashboard, select it, click the grey dropdown and choose *add filter* and select all the fields I want to create filters for; if you have the filters applied to multiple worksheets or to all worksheets using the same data source, your dashboard filters will work in the way which you desire.
[See more filtering documentation here](https://help.tableau.com/current/pro/desktop/en-us/filtering_global.htm)

Comment: The problem with that is when I add them to the work sheet the affect the visualizing. For example if I have a bar graph showing monthly sales of by region and normal it would be split into our 4 regions. Once I add products it now has 100 little segments in each bar for each product.  It only gets worse as I add all the other items.

Comment: Don't add them to the viz pane, add them to the filter box top left, I will edit my answer to include a screenshot.

Comment: My issue mainly was the filters. I did not have the exact same filters on both the source and destination page. I might have 1 extra which was causing an error. When I remove the the extra ones so they were identical lists, it then worked.